# How to port NDIS 6.2 to NDIS 6.3 using NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, ndis

I have NDIS 6.2 Supporting Miniport Driver . Now I want to port NDIS 6.2 to NDIS 6.3 .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn232191(v=vs.85).aspx

Using this link I changed some general requirements and Power Management for Enhancements in NDIS 6.30 .

i put all changes are in same NDIS 6.2 file .

The chnages are (miniport.cpp)

```
ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.MajorNdisVersion                = 6;
ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.MinorNdisVersion                = 30;

ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.MajorDriverVersion              = VERSION_MAJOR_NUM;
ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.MinorDriverVersion              = VERSION_MINOR_NUM;

ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.SetOptionsHandler               = CMiniport::SetOptions;
ndisMiniportDriverCharacteristics.InitializeHandlerEx             = CMiniport::InitializeEx;
```

...... ....etc

then inside InitializeEx() funcion the changes for `NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES` are :

```
NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes;
NdisZeroMemory(&ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes, sizeof(NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES));

#if (NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630)

C_ASSERT(sizeof(NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES) >= NDIS_SIZEOF_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_2);
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES;
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Size = NDIS_SIZEOF_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_2;
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Revision = NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_2;

#else

C_ASSERT(sizeof(NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES) >= NDIS_SIZEOF_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_1);
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES;
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Size = NDIS_SIZEOF_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_1;
ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.Header.Revision = NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_REGISTRATION_ATTRIBUTES_REVISION_1;

#endif // NDIS MINIPORT VERSION

ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.MiniportAdapterContext = CMiniport::m_pMiniport;


#if (NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630)

    ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.AttributeFlags |= NDIS_MINIPORT_ATTRIBUTES_NO_PAUSE_ON_SUSPEND;

#else

   ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.AttributeFlags = NDIS_MINIPORT_ATTRIBUTES_SURPRISE_REMOVE_OK | NDIS_MINIPORT_ATTRIBUTES_NDIS_WDM;

#endif  

ndisMiniportAdapterRegistrationAttributes.CheckForHangTimeInSeconds = 5;
```

and for the chnage NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES i wrote like this :

```
 NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES ndisPmCapabilities;
 NdisZeroMemory(&ndisPmCapabilities, sizeof(NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES));


#if (NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630)

    C_ASSERT(sizeof(NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES) >= NDIS_SIZEOF_NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_2);
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Size = NDIS_SIZEOF_NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_2;
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Revision = NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_2;

    ndisPmCapabilities.MinMagicPacketWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;
    ndisPmCapabilities.MinPatternWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;
    ndisPmCapabilities.MinLinkChangeWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;

#else

    C_ASSERT(sizeof(NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES) >= NDIS_SIZEOF_NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_1);
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Size = NDIS_SIZEOF_NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_1;
    ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Revision = NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_1;

    ndisPmCapabilities.MinMagicPacketWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;
    ndisPmCapabilities.MinPatternWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;
    ndisPmCapabilities.MinLinkChangeWakeUp = NdisDeviceStateUnspecified;

#endif // NDIS MINIPORT VERSION
```

So my doubts are :

1. can i use this NDIS 6.30 for windows 7 NDIS 6.2 ?
2. how to activate `NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630` macro ?

in ndis.h WDK file the macros are like this :

```
#if !defined(NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630)
#if  (((defined (NDIS_MINIPORT_MAJOR_VERSION) && (NDIS_MINIPORT_MAJOR_VERSION >= 6)) && \
       (defined (NDIS_MINIPORT_MINOR_VERSION) && (NDIS_MINIPORT_MINOR_VERSION >= 30))) || \
      (defined (NDIS630)) || NDIS_WRAPPER)
#define NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630      1
#else
#define NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630      0
#endif
#endif // !defined(NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630)
```

but when i use  `ndisPmCapabilities.Header.Revision = NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_2;` directly i got error like 
 `NDIS_PM_CAPABILITIES_REVISION_2 is not defined` .

How to use this  `NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS630` macro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You activate the relevant `NDIS` version by defining the appropriate `NDIS6XX_MINIPORT` in your project. You can see it in more details in comments at the beginning of `ndis.h` header.

You can compile your driver with whatever `NDIS` version that you want, but they are not backwards compatible - each Windows version is provided with a different `NDIS` version, naturally older `OS` versions can't work with newer `NDIS` versions.

Comment: It's working after changing NDIS630_MINIPORT=1 from NDIS620_MINIPORT=1 inside .vcxproj file . so the problem were in the build ommands .

Comment: Thanks for the information . So i should build my application speific to different OS ? like NDIS 6.2 - windows 7 and NDIS 6.3 - Windows 8 , 8.1 like this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you specify NDIS630_MINIPORT, your code should comply with NDIS 6.3 specification (which has some differences compared to NDIS 6.2, especially within the registration process). But the resulting driver won't install on Windows 7 because it doesn't support NDIS 6.3. You can target your driver to NDIS 6.2 and it should work on both Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: But when i use NDIS 6.2 , I got some crash on windows 8 , 8.1 . The dump file pointed out " ntoskrnl.exe " . I think this is due to power management pblm . That's why i port to NDIS 6.3 . so it will help me ? any idea ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without actual debugging

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not support NDIS 6.30.  Windows 7 only goes up to 6.20.

Comment: Ok . So can i use NDIS 6.3 driver for Windows 8 and later os ?

Comment: Yes Windows 8 supports NDIS 6.30

Comment: ok . But i got blue screen issue when i use NDIS 6.2 driver in windows 8 . After analyzing dump it pointed to ntoskrnl.exe  . i think it's due to power management issue .So that's why i updated to NDIS 6.3 .